# Inject a tag inside another tag in <head> using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, head, noscript

How do I inject  tag inside  in head using javascript.

```
<noscript>
     <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=801318466672120&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        /></noscript>
```

I tried

```
var nonscript = document.createElement('noscript');
    nonscript.innerHTML = "<img height='1' width='1' style='display:none' src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=801318466672120&ev=PageView&noscript=1'/>";
    head.appendChild(nonscript);
```

but it comes like

```
<noscript>
    "<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/tr id=801318466672120&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
        />" </noscript>
```

Comment: noscript is only visible if JS is disabled

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following code:

```
var nonscript = document.createElement('noscript');
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.height = 1;
img.width = 1;
img.style.display = "none";
img.src = "https://www.facebook.com/trid=801318466672120&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
nonscript.appendChild(img);
document.head.appendChild(nonscript);
```

Answer (score 2):

Appending a `noscript` tag with javascript makes no sense whatsoever.

Also, when used in the `head`, the `noscript` tag can not contain an `img`:

> **Permitted content**:    When scripting is disabled and when it is a
>   descendant of the `<head>` element: in any order, **zero or more `<link>`
>   elements**, **zero or more `<style>` elements**, and **zero or more `<meta>`
>   elements**. When scripting is disabled and when it isn't a descendant of
>   the `<head>` element: any transparent content, but no `<noscript>` element
>   must be among its descendants. Otherwise: flow content or phrasing
>   content.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)

But if you insist:

You need to create an `img` element and append that to your `noscript` element. You can then append both to `head`:

```
var nonscript = document.createElement('noscript');
var img = document.createElement('img');
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

img.width = "0";
img.height = "0";
img.style.display = "none";
img.src = "https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=801318466672120&ev=PageView&noscript=1";

nonscript.appendChild(img);
head.appendChild(nonscript);
```